# PHP: Can I put an If statement inside a variable and then call it somewhere later?

Tags: php

```
$tax_slab = if($yearly_income >= 600000 && <= 1200000)
{
    echo "5%";
}
```

I want to put that if statement inside a variable so I can call that variable somewhere else. I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm still a beginner but I want to put "if" inside "tax_slab"

Comment: `if (condition) { $var = 'something' }`

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via [ternary operator:](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

```
$tax_slab = $yearly_income >= 600_000 && $yearly_income <= 1_200_000 ? 5 : 0;
```

As you stated, you are still a beginner, but there are plenty of resources you can lookup easily than waiting here for someone to answer.
Take a look at [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/index.htm).

Furthermore, if you want to pursue development in PHP, I would also recommend taking a look at [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/).

Answer (score 0):

Hay i think that you need to see this [PHP control structures if](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

And to solve your problem you can do this

```
if($yearly_income >= 600000 &&  $yearly_income <= 1200000)
{
    $tax_slab="5%";
    echo $tax_slab;
}
```

let say that `$tax_slab=600001;`

the output will be

`5%`